# Linux email attach file

Tags: linux, bash, email, sendmail, ksh

```
send_mail(){

cat << EOF | /usr/sbin/sendmail -t ${TO_LIST}  -a ${file_path}/test.CSV
From: test@gmail.com
To: test@gmail.com
#Cc: $CC_LIST
Subject: test mail
Mime-Version: 1.0
Dear  User,
please find the attachment.
$result
$newline

$sign
EOF
}
```

tried multiple options but file is not getting attached, I verified the file exist.
Any suggestions

```
-bash-4.2$ uname -a
```

Linux `hostname` 3.10.0 #1 `date` GNU/Linux

Answer (score 0):

Try the sendmail command manually.  The -t option is not doing what you think it does.  Similarly for the -a, unless you are using a version of sendmail very different from Debian.